# some files not cached in requirejs - is that an issue?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, progressive-download

Using RequireJS I am developing my application. I noticed from my browser developer tools (attached) some of files (router.js, views.js, model.js, etc.) say cached "no". What does that mean? What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your require.config section? Perhaps you have the cache-busting parameter? What browser tools window is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this isn't a issue. The cache of RequireJS is not only client-side dependend. It's server-side dependent too. If you not define the correct headers (Expires, Max-Age, ETag, etc.), your browser can not cache the script, and the result is what you are checking in your developer tools.

I can that Cache Busting, as in the URL visible in your screenshot, is deactivated, and because this you can need only check the configurations in your server(s).

Good luck.